# Unable to contact DHCP on Windows 10, what to do?

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, ethernet, dhcp

I have just reinstalled Windows 10 on a Lenovo desktop but I cannot get the wired internet connection to work. I have it connected to a TP-Link TL-SG108 switch to which I have other machines connected too, and they do work.
Wifi works on the Lenovo,  and even the ethernet did work once after the new installation but after a restart it just won't connect again. Doing ipconfig /renew results in "Unable to contact your DHCP server".
I've tried reinstalling the network card, and most other advices I find on Google but without any luck.

This is what the ipconfig looks like right now:

[image: ipconfig]

Any help forward is appreciated!

Comment: Is the machine connected to a device that is acting like a DHCP server (i.e. AD Domain Server or a network router)?

Comment: The machine is connected to a network switch which in turn is connected to the fiber modem/router (whetever it's called) which comes from my internet provider. To the network switch I also have connected a wifi router and an apple TV, both works fine. I have made no config changes to the network switch (if that's even possible)

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue if the machine cannot communicate with the DHCP server on the router.

Comment: If you manually configure the ip settings on the wired interface is it able to get on the internet? If yes the problem is on the DHCP server. If not the problem is on the switch or the wiring.

Comment: I have not tried that since I'm not sure how it's done, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Type *troubleshoot* in *Settings* and run the network one.

Comment: yes, that is done. It finds the problem that "Ethernet is missing a valid IP configuration" but cannot repair it.

Comment: You don't have a default gateway. Make sure you check router settings as well.

Comment: Here's how to configure a static IP: [https://pureinfotech.com/set-static-ip-address-windows-10/#static_ip_controlpanel_windows10](https://pureinfotech.com/set-static-ip-address-windows-10/#static_ip_controlpanel_windows10). If your router's IP address is `192.168.0.1`, setting IP address to `192.168.0.50`, subnet mask to `255.255.255.0`, Default Gateway to `192.168.0.1` and DNS servers to `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1` allows you to connect to a website.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a broken cable, broken switch port or misconfigured wifi router. Move your network cable from the wifi router to your PC to check it.